# Seleccionar una opcion y añadirla a una lista

Tags: reactjs

estoy comenzando en react y no consigo lo que necesito. Vereis, tengo tres checkboxs, un campo y un boton. Se que a alguno le parecerá una pregunta que ni debería hacerse, pero no tengo ni idea de como hacer. Lo que quiero es que al seleccionar un checkbox, al darle al boton agregar, me aparezca esa elección en el campo que esta debajo de los checkboxs. Se que tiene que ir una función pero le he dado muchas vueltas y no lo logro. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

````
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {


  const [list, setList] = useState([])


  return (
    <>


<div class="ui checkbox">
  <input type="checkbox" name="coche"/>
  <label>coche</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="moto"/>
  <label>moto</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="bici"/>
  <label>bici</label>
</div>


<div></div>
<form class="ui form">
  <div class="field">
    <label>Valores</label>
    <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name"/>
  </div>

  <div><button>Agregar</button></div>
  </form>

    
    </>
  )
}

export default App;```
````

Answer (score 1):

hay muchas maneras de conseguir lo que quieres, pero acá te va una solución.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [inputVal, setInputVal] = useState("");
  const [list, setList] = useState([]);

  const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
    const { name, checked } = e.target;
    if (checked) setList((prev) => [...prev, name]);
    else setList((prev) => prev.filter((n) => n !== name));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputVal(list.join(", "));
  }, [list]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="ui checkbox">
        <input onChange={handleCheckboxChange} type="checkbox" name="coche" />
        <label>coche</label>
        <input onChange={handleCheckboxChange} type="checkbox" name="moto" />
        <label>moto</label>
        <input onChange={handleCheckboxChange} type="checkbox" name="bici" />
        <label>bici</label>
      </div>

      <div></div>
      <form className="ui form">
        <div className="field">
          <label>Valores</label>
          <input
            value={inputVal}
            onChange={(t) => setInputVal(t.target.value)}
            type="text"
            name="first-name"
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
        </div>

        <div>
          <button>Agregar</button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </>
  );
}
```

Si ves `handleCheckboxChange` es el handle para todos los checkboxes. Lo único que hace es revisar el valor `checked` del checkbox, si es true agrega el name al final de la lista, si es false remueve el `name`. Y luego el `useEffect` se va a ejecutar cada vez que la `list` cambie y va a unir los valores por una coma y asignarlos al `inputVal`.